# Running geoip module with nginx

Tags: nginx, geoip

I have the regular nginx library installed on ubuntu and I would like to add geoip feature to this project. I read that I need to load the geoip module and i installed it, I think, via apt-get but I am stuck at this level as I am not sure how to load nginx with this new module running alongside it. I already installed the cities and country database to the server.

Answer (score 1):

When you run:
`nginx -V`

Do you see `--with-http_geoip_module`, if not you should update your nginx.

If visible follow the following article to install and download the IP to Geo DB from Maxmind.

https://www.howtoforge.com/nginx-how-to-block-visitors-by-country-with-the-geoip-module-debian-ubuntu

Comment: Yes I do see that flag.

Comment: Ok you are good to use the module! Check this out https://www.howtoforge.com/nginx-how-to-block-visitors-by-country-with-the-geoip-module-debian-ubuntu

Comment: Do you have any insight on how to pass the geo_city name to be accessed by my scripts?

Comment: yes, you have to use proxy pass and pass it as a header

Comment: Ahh I see, thanks for the help, I will try to see where I can take it from there

Comment: i followed everything, but still the value of country code variable is undefined... im stuck pls help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51282599/nginx-geoip-module-undefined-country-code